# Не получается изменить цвет static, после того, как окно уже появилось

Tags: winapi, c++

Доброго времени суток!
В диалоговом окне есть static и кнопка. Хочу, чтобы по нажатию кнопки изменялся цвет static'а.
Код обработки статика:

> ```
> case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:{
>           HDC hDC = (HDC)wParam;
>           SetBkMode(hDC, TRANSPARENT);
>
>           if ((HWND)lParam == GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDS_NICK)){ // nick
>
>               if (nick) SetTextColor(hDC, RGB(0, 255, 0));
>               else SetTextColor(hDC, RGB(255, 0, 0));
>
>               return (int)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
>           }
>       break;}
> ```

Ну и соответственно нажатие кнопки:

> ```
> case IDB_NICK:
>       nick = true;
>       SendMessage(hDlg, WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, 
>                  (WPARAM)GetDC(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDS_NICK)), 
>                  (LPARAM)GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDS_NICK));
> break;
> ```

Дебаг показывает, что после нажатия кнопки я прекрасно попадаю в обработку статика, все идет как надо, но перерисовка не происходит:( Т.е. когда окошко открывается, то цвет сразу красный, все хорошо. Если нажать на кнопку, то ничего не происходит. А если открыть и закрыть длг окно, то цвет статика станет зеленым (т.к. еще по нажатию флажок nick изменился).

В общем главный вопрос, как изменить цвет статика во время работы диалогового окна?
Добавление UpdateWindow в обработку кнопки не помогает:)

Премного благодарен!:)

Comment: думаю только UpdateWindow не поможет надо область которую надо перерисовать объявить дефектной с помощью функции [InvalidateRect][1]  а затем обработать сообщение WM_PAINT


  [1]: http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/winapi/r.php?69

Comment: да, точно:) я почему-то думал, что за отрисовку именно статиков отвечает wm_ctlcolorstatic, а в msdn оказывается упустил  is ABOUT to be drawn.
спасибо большое:)

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать функцию [InvalidateRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd145002(v=vs.85).aspx)